# show all autofilter data on workbook close save password protected

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to **show all filtered data** when a sheet is closed, but how can I do this on a protected sheet as some of the users have a habit of deleting important elements of the sheet?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sh As Variant
    For Each sh In Worksheets
         If sh.FilterMode Then sh.ShowAllData
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim sh As Variant
    For Each sh In Worksheets
      If sh.FilterMode Then sh.ShowAllData
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So within your `For loop` if you **unprotect** the sheets , **run your macro** and then **protect** the sheets again this will solve your problem.

For that reason I'm going to add `Worksheet.Unprotect` and `.Protect` within your code.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sh As Variant
    For Each sh In Worksheets
         sh.Unprotect Password:= "YourPasswordHere"     'leave this quotation marks empty if you don't have password
         If sh.FilterMode Then sh.ShowAllData
        sh.Protect Password:= "YourPasswordHere"
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim sh As Variant
    For Each sh In Worksheets
      sh.Unprotect Password:= "YourPasswordHere"  
      If sh.FilterMode Then sh.ShowAllData
      sh.Protect Password:= "YourPasswordHere"
    Next
End Sub
```

*PS: As an option, you can also control which functions can users be able to use in protected sheet with these below codes, you can changes **False/True** to do the action.*

```
.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows _
:=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
.EnableOutlining = True
```

Comment: The removal of all filtering works, but im unsure how it can ben enabled with the above code when a new user opens up the protected sheet as its disabled currently?